# RRD Time since last non-change of counter

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have a RRD DCOUNTER, which gets its data from the water meter: so many units since start of the program which looks at the meter.

So the input might be 2,3,4,5,5,5,5,8,12,13,13,14,14,14,14,14
That means the flow is 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,3,4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0

I want a graph showing minutes since last rest
0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5

If the flow is never zero, there must be a leak.
Hopefully the graph should rise steadily from bedtime to wakeup, and from leaving to work to coming back.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, you set up your input data source as a COUNTER type, so that you will be storing the changes, IE the flow.

Now, you can define a calculated datasource  (for graphs etc) that counts the minutes since the last zero, using something like:

`IF ( flow == 0 ) 
THEN
   timesincerest = 0
ELSE
   timesincerest = previous value of timesincerest + 1
END`

In RPN, that would be:

`timesincerest = flow, 0, GT, PREV(timesincerest), STEPWIDTH, +, 0, IF`

This will give you a count of the number of seconds since the last reset.

Comment: Thank you, but after removing the spaces, which rrdcgi appearently doesn't like, I only get " (mod_cgi.c.1319) cleaning up CGI: process died with signal 11" in the webserver log.

Comment: The STEPWIDTH is a relatively new item, so if you have an old RRDTool version it may not work - replace it with whatever your step size is.  You might also want to post the entire command parameters you are giving to rrdcgi in order to make sure that you have the rest of the syntax correct.